# ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python

When I run this code:

```
~/cdec/training/mira/mira.py -d dev.lc-tok.es-en.sgm -t devtest.lc-tok.es-en.sgm -c cdec.ini -j 2
```

I receive this error message:

```
 File "~/prefix/sw/cdec/training/mira/mira.py", line 551, in <module>
    main()
  File "~/prefix/sw/cdec/training/mira/mira.py", line 204, in main
    args.weights, hope_best_fear = optimize(args, script_dir, dev_size)
  File "~/prefix/sw/cdec/training/mira/mira.py", line 327, in optimize
    (source, refs) = split_devset(args.devset, args.output_dir)
  File "~/prefix/sw/cdec/training/mira/mira.py", line 314, in split_devset
    s,r = line.strip().split(' ||| ',1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

That's happening in [this script](https://github.com/redpony/cdec/blob/master/training/mira/mira.py)

Can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Literally speaking, what is happening here is the code expects two values out the back of `line.strip().split(' ||| ',1)` (so it can assign those to `s` and `r`) but it's only getting one. Thus it explodes.

That's happening because you're not using the script correctly. If you look at the `--help` (or further up the code, line ~90), you'll see that it expects a very specific format:

```
parser.add_argument('-d', '--devset', required=True,
                    help='dev set input file in parallel. '
                    'format: src ||| ref1 ||| ref2')
```

You aren't following that so it can't split and therefore explodes.